# Solr Jetty Bitnami MySQL Driver Configuration

Tags: mysql, solr, jetty, datasource

the jetty.xml is as follows

```
<New id="SomeID" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg></Arg>
    <Arg>jdbc/MyDB</Arg>
    <Arg>
        <New class="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver">
            <Set name="Url">jdbc:mysql://some_connectoin/mydb</Set>
            <Set name="User">user Name</Set>
            <Set name="Password">PAssword</Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</New>
```

But on running it gives error 
"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
"org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration  – Config error at

"mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar" has been placed in ./lib folder of jetty

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just placing the jar in the `${jetty.base}/lib` (or `${jetty.home}/lib` if using versions of Jetty older than Jetty 9), will not make it available for the server to use.

**If you have a Jetty 9:**

1. put the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar` in `${jetty.base}/lib/ext` directory
2. add `--module=ext` the `${jetty.base}/start.ini`
3. test that it shows up on the server classpath

   ```
   $ java -jar /path/to/jetty.home/start.jar --list-classpath
   ```

**If you are using Jetty 7 or Jetty 8:**

1. put the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar` in the `${jetty.home}/lib/ext` directory
2. open up the `${jetty.home}/start.ini` and ensure that the `OPTIONS` line has `ext` in it
3. test that it shows up on the server classpath

   ```
   $ java -jar start.jar --version
   ```